# How to declare array of custom Class object in Swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

ObjectiveC Code:

```
CCButton *mNumTiles[10];
```

I Tried this Swift code but Crashing

```
var mNumTiles : [CCButton]! 

mNumTiles[0] = CCButton.buttonWithTitle(""
```

How to declare array of custom Class object in Swift ?

Comment: You merely declared the variable, but you didn't initialize it.

Comment: That's not Objective-C code, but rather plain old C code... I mean, it's not an `NSArray` but a C-style array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've *declared* an array but haven't *initialized* one.

You can do it like this:

```
var mNumTiles = [CCButton]()

mNumTiles.append(CCButton(title: ""))
```

Note that you don't have to declare the type of `mNumTiles`; Swift will infer it from the initialization (`[CCButton]()`)

Comment: still I got error for this answer, see this https://app.box.com/s/3fxu72z2l7rsz7ln6lt0gcmhdp1pcg47

Comment: @iPhoneChip That's because you typed something different than what I wrote. Change `:` to `=`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var mNumTiles : [CCButton] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the array:

```
var mNumTiles = [CCButton]()
```

And then you can append into it.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable declaration is incorrect, because the variable is not initialized (`nil`). To do that, you have to construct an array like this

```
var mNumTiles : [CCButton]! = [CCButton](count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Another way to do it would be to initialize an empty array and use `append` to add the button:

```
var mNumTiles : [CCButton]! = []
mNumTiles.append(CCButton....)
```

---

You should make sure to read this if you want to learn more about arrays in Swift:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html

Comment: still getting compiler error for this answer see https://app.box.com/s/x8ytawnn9njzl2cuxkagwf7v96qdd5vi